# Meteor fails to install on local machine

Tags: meteor

I tried installing the meteor executable file on my local machine. meteor --version turned up nothing on the command line. I then tried npm install meteor on powershell and got this:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm install -g meteor
npm WARN deprecated mongodb@1.1.11: Please upgrade to 2.2.19 or higher
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.3.3: Use uuid module instead
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm\meteor -> C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\meteor\app\meteor\meteor.js

> bson@0.1.5 install C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\meteor\node_modules\bson
> node install.js || (exit 0)

================================================================================
=                                                                              =
=  Attempting to build bson c++ extension                                      =
=   Windows: no build will be attempted as binaries are prepackaged            =
=   Unix: on failure the package will still install without the C++ extension  =
=                                                                              =
================================================================================

> fibers@0.6.9 install C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\meteor\node_modules\fibers
> node ./build.js

(node:9716) DeprecationWarning: child_process: options.customFds option is deprecated. Use options.stdio instead.
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn node-gyp ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:393:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:508:3
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "ins
tall" "-g" "meteor"
npm ERR! node v6.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! fibers@0.6.9 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@0.6.9 install script 'node ./build.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./build.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs fibers
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

---

The same command on Git Bash turned the same result. How can this be resolved? I should note that I tried "run as administrator" for powershell and git bash.

Comment: The right way of installing meteor on windows is using the official installer for now. You can find it here : https://www.meteor.com/install

Answer (score 0):

On windows, install meteor using the meteor installer:
https://www.meteor.com/install

Comment: I tried the installer but it also fails to show a version when I type meteor --version

Comment: If you have access to the meteor cli try meteor show meteor